ANY function used with dates to return the date/s in R
i have data like so:



Date of Dose 2
episode_1
episode_2
episode_3
episode_4
episode_5




2022-01-15
2022-02-01
2021-12-25
NA
2022-03-01
NA



I need to identify the dates which are 14 days greater than the date of dose 2 from the 5 episode columns. output should be:



Date of BI




2022-02-01, 2022-03-01



what I have tried so far:

vaccine_received_test <- vaccine_received %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    dose_2_plus_14 = `Date of Dose 2` + days(14),
    
    # Check if any episode date is greater than 'Date of Dose 2 + 14 days'
    date_of_BI = case_when(
          any(c(episode_1, episode_2, episode_3, episode_4, episode_5) > dose_2_plus_14, 
          na.rm = TRUE) ~ any(c(episode_1, episode_2, episode_3, episode_4, episode_5), 
          TRUE ~ NA
    )
  )


any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Is it about just one row?

no. I just included one row as sample data

I suspect that life would be easier if you pivoted your data to long format.

You could pivot, then filter, then pivot:
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

pivot_longer(df, -1) |>
  filter(value-`Date of Dose 2`>14) |>
  pivot_wider(id_cols=1)
___
# A tibble: 1 × 3
  `Date of Dose 2` episode_1  episode_4 
  <date>           <date>     <date>    
1 2022-01-15       2022-02-01 2022-03-01


Data:
df <- structure(list(`Date of Dose 2` = structure(19007, class = "Date"), 
    episode_1 = structure(19024, class = "Date"), episode_2 = structure(18986, class = "Date"), 
    episode_3 = NA, episode_4 = structure(19052, class = "Date"), 
    episode_5 = NA), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))


Thank you so much! This worked like a charm. Mind blowingly simple solution!

With dplyr, you can use select() with where():
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  select(where(~ difftime(.x, df[["Date of Dose 2"]]) > 14 & !is.na(.x)))

# # A tibble: 1 × 2
#   episode_1  episode_4 
#   <date>     <date>    
# 1 2022-02-01 2022-03-01


And a fairly obscure Base
df[, c(1, which(difftime(apply(df[1, ], 1, as.POSIXct)[2:6], 
      apply(df[1, ], 1, as.POSIXct)[1]) > 14)+1)]
  Date of Dose 2  episode_1  episode_4
1     2022-01-15 2022-02-01 2022-03-01

where apply here both provides the above @limey suggested 'go long' and transform to POSIXct.
